# Windows Batch: Replace newline characters to create csv file

Tags: batch-file, awk, sed

I have an output file which is a deconstructed csv file.

```
a
,b
,c
e
,f
,g
,h
i 
,j 
.......
```

The number of elements is random in each line. And each element is random also. I want to replace '\r\n,'  with ','. But i cant find the syntax for to do it.....

```
a,b,c
e,f,g,h 
i,j 
.......
```

I cant install third-party utilities on the server but have access to an older version of unixutils

```
GNU textutils 1.5
GNU sed version 3.02
GNU Awk 3.1.0
```

Any help greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` version

```
awk 'NR>1 {printf "%s"($0~/^,/?"":RS),a} {a=$0} END {print $0}' file
a,b,c
e,f,g,h
i ,j
```

You have a space after `i` in your input file, its not removed. If you like to remove it do:

```
awk 'NR>1 {printf "%s"($0~/^,/?"":RS),a} {sub(/ +$/,"");a=$0} END {print $0}' file
a,b,c
e,f,g,h
i,j
```

Comment: Your a star with a guitar! Thats perfect!

Comment: @DanielA please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Batch file below does not require any third-party utilities (including GNU's):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "out="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
   set "in=%%a"
   if "!in:~0,1!" neq "," (
      if defined out echo !out!
      set "out=!in!"
   ) else (
      set "out=!out!!in!"
   )
)
echo !out!
```

This program will fail if the lines contain exclamation marks. This point may be fixed.

Comment: **+1**.  One doesn't see quality batch programming so much anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Another `sed` option:

```
$ sed -ne '/^,/H;/^[^,]/{;x;s/\r\n//g;/./p;};${;x;s/\r\n//g;p;}' input
a,b,c
e,f,g,h
i,j
```

Broken out for easier reading, here's how this one works:

- `/^,/H;` -- For any line that starts with a comma, append it to sed's "hold".
- `/^[^,]/{` -- For any line that *doesn't* start with a comma (which means we're at the end of the previous set of input lines):

  - `x;` -- swap the pattern and hold spaces (so the start of the next line is in the hold),
  - `s/\r\n//g;` -- remove all newlines in the pattern,
  - `/./p;};` -- and if there's actually a pattern here (i.e. not a blank line), print it.
- `${x;s/\r\n//g;p}` -- then do the same at the end of the file.

Note that this should work with non-GNU sed as well as GNU.  I tested it in FreeBSD and OSX, though with unix-style line endings, then added the `\r` to the substitutions for this answer.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I got this with awk:

```
awk '/,/{x=x$0;next} {if(length(x))print x;x=$0}' file
```

If there is a comma on the line, add this line to variable `x`. If not, print `x` if there is anything in it and start a new `x` using the current line.

Comment: This wont print the last line as print is never called again due to no more lines without a `,`

Answer (score 0):

Another awk way

```
awk '/,/{x=x$0}!/,/{if(x)print x;x=$0}END{print x}' file
```

And another without whitespace

```
awk '/,/{x=x$0}!/,/{x?x=x"\n"$0:x=$0}END{gsub(/ /,"",x);print x}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the input Record Separator and the Output Record Separator appropriately:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n,' -v ORS=',' '1' file
```

Or read the whole file in and do a global subsitution:

```
awk -v RS='^$' '{gsub(/\r\n,/,",")}1' file
```

Depending on the platform you're running on, you may need to add `-v BINMODE=3` to stop the C utils from stripping the `\r` before awk gets a chance to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed also

```
sed  ':loop ; N ;s/\n//g ; s/\(\w\)\(\w\)/\1\n\2/g ; t loop ' file_name
```